# Django Two seperate user profile regsitration, login and logout view funciton implementation failed

Tags: mysql, authentication, email, stripe-payments, django-authentication

I need to develop a different e-commerce project with the Django Rest Framework and ReactJS integrated through Axios. But I wonder how to implement two separate users like farmers as a vendor and customers who buy produce from farmers. The registered profile could be saved on the MySQL database. When Farmer or Customer user tries to log in API view function the login credentials must be validated from the MySQL database. I wish to use Basic Authentication instead of token-based authentication. And stripe payment gateway was also implemented.
The existing Django

**models.py:**

```
import stripe
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from stripe.error import CardError
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

# Farmer model
class Farmer(AbstractBaseUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    aadhaar_card = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    stripe_connect_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = password
    
    def check_password(self, password):
        pass

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'farmer'


# Customer model
class Customer(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    aadhaar_card = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = password

    def check_password(self, password):
        return self.password == password

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customer' 


# Product Category model
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'category'

    

# Product model
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    farmer = models.ForeignKey(Farmer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_farmer_address(self):
        return self.farmer.address

    def get_farmer_city(self):
        return self.farmer.city

    def get_farmer_state(self):
        return self.farmer.state

    def get_farmer_zip_code(self):
        return self.farmer.zip_code

    def get_farmer_mobile_number(self):
        return self.farmer.mobile_number
    class Meta:
        index_together = (('name', 'category'),)
        db_table = 'product'

# Order model
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'order'

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'orderitem'


# Payment model
class Payment(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    stripe_charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('payment_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def charge(self, request):
        try:
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=int(self.amount * 100),
                currency='usd',
                description=self.product.name,
                source=request.POST['stripeToken']
            )
            self.stripe_charge_id = charge['id']
            return True
        except CardError as e:
            self.stripe_charge_id = e.error.payment_intent.id
            return False

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'payment'


# Cart model
class Cart(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_total_price(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cart'
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers, generics
from .models import Farmer, Customer, Category, Product, Order, OrderItem, Payment, Cart


class FarmerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Farmer
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'gender', 'aadhaar_card',
            'stripe_connect_id'
        )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        farmer = Farmer(**validated_data)
        farmer.set_password(password)
        farmer.save()
        return farmer

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'mobile_number', 'gender', 'aadhaar_card'
        )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        customer = Customer(**validated_data)
        customer.set_password(password)
        customer.save()
        return customer


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    farmer = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='farmer.id')
    farmer_address = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='farmer.address')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'image', 'category', 'price', 'farmer', 'farmer_address')


class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.id')
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('id', 'product', 'quantity')


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='customer.id')
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'order_items', 'order_date')

class PaymentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='customer.id')
    product = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.id')
    amount = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    payment_date = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    stripe_charge_id = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'product', 'amount', 'payment_date', 'stripe_charge_id')


class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.id')
    quantity = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ('id', 'product', 'quantity')


class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_fields = ('farmer_address',)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from rest_framework import generics, authentication, permissions, status
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings


from .models import Product, Farmer, Cart, Order, Payment, OrderItem
from .serializers import FarmerSerializer, CustomerSerializer, ProductSerializer, CartSerializer, OrderSerializer, PaymentSerializer


# Farmer registration view
class FarmerRegistrationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'message': 'GET method is allowed for registration.'})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = FarmerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            farmer = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)  # Return serialized data
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)



class FarmerLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        farmer = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if farmer is not None:
            login(request, farmer)
            return Response({'message': 'Login successful'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)



# Farmer logout view
class FarmerLogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Logout successful'}, status=200)


# Customer registration view
class CustomerRegistrationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'message': 'GET method is allowed for registration.'})

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            customer = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)  # Return serialized data
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)



# Customer login view
class CustomerLoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        customer = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if customer is not None:
            login(request, customer)
            return Response({'message': 'Login successful'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


# Customer logout view
class CustomerLogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Logout successful'}, status=200)

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        farmer_ids = Farmer.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
        return Product.objects.filter(farmer__in=farmer_ids)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class ProductCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # Set the farmer as the current user (assuming you are using authentication)
        serializer.save(farmer=self.request.user)

class ProductUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class ProductDeleteView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    
class CartView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CartSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            cart = serializer.save(customer=request.user.customer)
            return Response({'message': 'Product added to cart successfully.'})
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        try:
            cart_item = Cart.objects.get(pk=pk, customer=request.user.customer)
            cart_item.delete()
            return Response({'message': 'Cart item deleted successfully.'})
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'error': 'Cart item not found.'}, status=404)


class CheckoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(customer=request.user.customer, ordered=False)
        if not cart_items:
            return Response({'error': 'No items in the cart.'}, status=400)

        order = Order.objects.create(customer=request.user.customer)
        total_price = 0
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
                order=order,
                product=cart_item.product,
                quantity=cart_item.quantity
            )
            total_price += order_item.product.price * order_item.quantity
            cart_item.ordered = True
            cart_item.save()

        payment_url = self.create_payment_gateway_url(total_price)  # Replace with your payment gateway logic

        # Send order confirmation email
        send_mail(
            'Order Confirmation',
            'Your order has been confirmed. Please proceed with the payment by clicking the link below: {}'.format(payment_url),
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [request.user.customer.email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

        return Response({'message': 'Order created successfully. Proceed to payment.'})

    def create_payment_gateway_url(self, total_price):
        # Implement your payment gateway integration logic here
        # Return the payment gateway URL for the customer to proceed with payment
        payment_gateway_url = f"https://example.com/payment_gateway?amount={total_price}"  # Replace with your payment gateway URL
        return payment_gateway_url


class PaymentView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # Process the payment and handle the payment gateway response
        # Update the order status accordingly and send appropriate email notifications
        return Response({'message': 'Payment processed successfully.'})


class PaymentDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        # Retrieve the payment details for a specific order
        # Return the payment details in the response
        return Response({'message': 'Payment details for order {}.'.format(pk)})
```

**urls.py:**

API path URLs:

```
    path('api/farmers/register/', FarmerRegistrationView.as_view(), name='farmer-register'),
    path('api/farmer/login/', FarmerLoginView.as_view(), name='farmer-login'),
    path('api/farmer/logout/', FarmerLogoutView.as_view(), name='farmer-logout'),

    path('api/customer/register/', CustomerRegistrationView.as_view(), name='customer-register'),
    path('api/customer/login/', CustomerLoginView.as_view(), name='customer-login'),
    path('api/customer/logout/', CustomerLogoutView.as_view(), name='customer-logout'),
    
    path('api/product/list/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product-list'),

    path('api/product/create/', ProductCreateView.as_view(), name='product-create'),
    path('api/product/update/<int:pk>/', ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='product-update'),
    path('api/product/delete/<int:pk>/', ProductDeleteView.as_view(), name='product-delete'),

    path('api/cart/', CartView.as_view(), name='cart'),
    path('api/cart/delete/<int:pk>/', CartView.as_view(), name='cart-delete'),

    path('api/checkout/', CheckoutView.as_view(), name='checkout'),
    path('api/payment/', PaymentView.as_view(), name='payment'),
    path('api/payment/<int:pk>/', PaymentDetail.as_view(), name='payment-detail'),
```

When new farmer or customer users tried to login view they should able to login into the these E-Commerce web app without authentication error. These credentials validated from MySQL database data.

Farmer and Customer registration properly working.

Guys please guide me for project development. Including, Farmer and Customer Registration, Login, Logout. After farmer user successful login they can able to do crud operation in product to add new product with product images.

After customer user successful login they can able to use Cart option to add product and then they can also use order function to purchase those product. When they click checkout button they should be redirected to stripe payment gateway. For successful payment they should receive acknowledgement in mail notification.

Please guys...project submission date deadline almost closed. Help me to complete this entire project.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).